# How to post grid data in the form of List object to the controller in mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to post grid values from view to controller. I have created grid through javascript and i am getting the grid values into an object

```
   $(".TCtable tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
            var this_row = $(this);
             var storeid= $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
            var status= $(this).find('td:eq(2) input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val()?true:false;

            var object = {

                storeid: storeid, 
                status: status
            };
            array.push(object);
```

I am posting this to controller using json

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Savedetails", "Field")',
              type: 'POST',            
              //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              datatype: 'json',
              //data:jsonText,
              data:{jsonPackage:JSON.stringify(array)},
              success: function (response) {
              },
              error: function (error) {
              }
          });
```

and my controller is

```
  public JsonResult SaveDetails(List<FieldAssignmentGridViewModel> data)
        {
    }
```

The values are coming to array list. but i am not able to send this json obect to the controller. List goes empty. Can someone please help me out .
How to get the list in the controller?

Comment: Why are you not just posting back your model?

Comment: can u tell me how can i do that ? I am loading grid through javascript.

Comment: if data is send in json, why not use Javascriptdeserilizer to deserlize in list ?

Comment: Assuming your view is `@model List<FieldAssignmentGridViewModel>` and your constructing your html correctly using the html helpers inside a `for` loop or using an `EditorTemplate` then it would just need to be `data: $('form').serialize(),`. But with you existing code I suspect you also need to add `traditional: true,` since your not posting back indexed property names.

Comment: Note also if you use `JSON.stringify()` then you need to set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (otherwise don't use `.stringify()`)

Comment: i have printed the grid using ajax post.  can I get the list from there ?

Comment: @user3518928, Have just tested this. You just need to uncomment `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (it will correctly bind assuming `FieldAssignmentGridViewModel` contains properties `storeid` and `status`)

Comment: Yep. I am getting values in the alert. But the list is empty on controller. Posting wise ok. But controller i am not able to get the list

Comment: in controller how can i get the object values

Comment: @user3518928, You code works if you include `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. If its not binding then show you model for `FieldAssignmentGridViewModel`